# Is there a way to hide the Apply button on an Exposed Contextual Filter?

Tags: views

I'm using an Exposed Contextual Filter in a view. It's working nicely; however for aesthetics, we'd like to remove the Apply button and have the view change when the pull down does. How might I accomplish this?

[image]

### Follow up:

Thanks to both of you Lance and agargy below. Yes, hide the Apply button by checking 'Hide submit button'.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a standard feature. Go to the "Exposed Form" settings on your view and click "Settings" next to "Exposed form styles". I don't remember the correct name of the option but i think you get it when you're there.

Comment: Under Advanced -> Exposed Form -> Settings -> You'll find an option called "Autosubmit". Check it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you +Lance and +agargy. I'd mark this answer correct, but I have to wait three more minutes. In any case. Thanks again. I posted a 'follow up' section above with a screen shot showing someone else where to click.

Comment: That works fine if you have a dropdown or similar, but how do you hide it if the exposed filter is a text input? Auto-submit is not an option in that case.

Comment: Anyone know of a fix for the same issue but for drupal 8? Thanks